# Why this Implicit Binding is not working? - Laravel

Tags: laravel, routes, controller

I'm using Laravel 9. I have a problem, i wil appreciate any help.

I Have a Model named Entity, a controller EntityControler, and a FormRequest UpdateEntityRequest.

My API Routes looks like:

```
    Route::apiResource('entities', EntityController::class);
```

so i have show, create, store, update, delete... routes.

This is muy update method in EntityController (without the code/not important now)

```
public function update(UpdateEntityRequest $request, Entity $entity)
{
   return $entity;
}
```

the update method works perfect. But I want another update method for only a section and here starts the problem.

This is my new API Routes:

```
    Route::apiResource('entities', EntityController::class);
    Route::patch('/entities/{id}/{section}',[EntityController::class, 'updateSection' ]);
```

And this is the new method in the controller(without code yet):

```
public function updateSection( UpdateEntityRequest $request,Entity $entity, $section)
{
    return $entity;
}
```

But this last method return [] insted of the Entity and the update method works. WHY?
I change de uri in Postman for update PUT *{{baseUrl}}/entities/1* and for updateSection  *{{baseUrl}}/entities/1/1* .

Why does work in update and not in updateSection?

PD:
This method work, and give the id, and I can create a Entity from this:
public function updateSection( UpdateEntityRequest $request, $entity, $section)
{
return $entity;
}
But this is not what I want. Any idea why this happen?

Comment: please make sure your uri segment is same as the variable name in the controller

Answer (score 2, accepted):

please make sure your uri segment is same as the variable name in the controller, in your case replace `id` with `entity`

```
Route::patch('/entities/{entity}/{section}',[EntityController::class, 'updateSection' ]);
```

for more please see [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/routing#implicit-binding)

Answer (score 1):

Make the route param name consistent in your route api.php and your function updateSection in  EntityController

```
Route::patch('/entities/{entity}/{section}',[EntityController::class, 'updateSection' ]);
```

and

```
public function updateSection( UpdateEntityRequest $request,Entity $entity, $section)
{
    return $entity;
}
```

Comment: I want to use the Entity model in the arguments, not only de id

Comment: Then you can go for this (see updated answer)